# If the request contains StringArray data，Dose request.getParameterNames().nextElement() contains value with "[]"?

Tags: java, request, tomcat7

Hello ！This is my first question in here.

My English is poor，Please bear with me.

This is my Java web program:

```
     Enumeration<String> paraNameStrArr = request.getParameterNames(); //javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request;
     while (paraNameStrArr.hasMoreElements()) {
     String paraNameStr = paraNameStrArr.nextElement();
     if (paraNameStr.endsWith("[]")){
        //With the same request，In my partner's computer it could into，but me couldn't
     }
}
```

It's very strange，I wonder why and how to fix it？

Here is my development environment:

- Win10  OS
- JDK 1.7.0_55
- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3
- Tomcat7.0.56 (My partner is Tomcat7.0.41)
- spring-webmvc 3.2.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

try using  request.getParameterMap()